# What is the best way to organize analytics code in Android App?

Tags: android, google-analytics, localytics

So right now I have one file(Lets say Analytics Helper) which has methods which different activities call. These methods accepts data and then create events(along with properties - custom data) and tag them. But this file will keep growing(as different events have different properties), which will make the code unmaintainable and untestable. So looking for the the best practices for organizing analytics code. 
Thanks for helping in advance